# build only a changed files from github through Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

How to build only a changed files from GitHub through Jenkins?

Commit1 commit10 are the commits checked in on GitHub.

Build is completed till commit1. In the next build remaining changes should build in Jenkins. Means

I want to build from commit2 to commit10 to my next build through Jenkins.

Comment: To clarify are you pushing all those commits at the same time to GitHub?

Comment: no, it would be some days. but that is  my next build @PeterReid

Comment: So you only want to 'build' the files that have changed???? I'm not really sure what you're getting at

Comment: yes, I want to build the files that have changed by developer @PeterReid

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is Jenkins to run each time there are changes in your Github repo.

This is easily done with checking the "Poll SCM" option in your build configuration and set the desired polling schedule:

[image]

Comment: Webhooks are recommended to ensure every commit gets built.

Comment: To expand on @osowskit's comment - it's not every commit that will be built, push events trigger a build of the latest commit on that branch

Comment: yes, I want to build the files that have changed and checked in by developer to GitHub @PeterReid